# Just open the link

Tags: shell, firefox

I just want to open a website link using the terminal in ubuntu. I am using the following code:-

firefox https://anylink.com

the problem is that once this command is executed, the terminal does not get free until and unless I close mozilla or press ctrl+c. I want to execute few more codes after the browser gets opened. What should I do???

Answer (score 2):

Add a & character to the end of your command, this will free the terminal after the command executes.

So you'd use

`firefox https://anylink.com &`

Answer (score 0):

I read the fine manual, and the following worked for me:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ firefox -new-window http://www.example.com/

(process:4094): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
thufir@doge:~$
```

there's also `new-tab` if that works better for you.

`man firefox` was useful.